# Mandrill SendEmail and get webhooks parse cloud code javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, cloud, sendmail, mandrill

Created a parse cloud function to send an email via MandrillApp to all recipients, can able to send all emails. But not able to see the logs, status(delivered/Rejected/Bounce) of sent email.
Created a webhook for them and called that when we invoke sendemail cloud function.
How can I request for webhooks results. I like to get the status of the email.

Can anyone of experts work on this, pl. share your inputs to accomplish this.. It will be helpful if you give detailed code.

Thanks in advance